# Access params inside params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Form on submit sends `params[:model]`, which inside have other hashes, like `:attribute_1=>value_1`

For example, server log:

```
Started POST "/tests/1/create_answer" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-26 04:36:09 +0400
Processing by TestsController#create_answer as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sFZIbaxVSnf1auEbsGMdVVl7dg0OWXKnFA0pl1aXA9o=", "answer"=>{"user_answer"=>"ssss", "position"=>"96", "key_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"", "id"=>"1"}
```

Is there way to acces any of this attributes in controller, some kind of:

```
@key=Key.find(params[:answer][:key_id])
```

Tried this, returns nil.

Comment: params[:answer][:key_id] should work... something similar has worked for me. Have you checked if that alone returns the right value? If so, then the next thing I can think of is whether find() requires an integer instead of a string i.e. find(params[:answer][:key_id].to_i)?

Comment: Note that determining if you're able to access the param value is easy: log it, puts it, binding.pry it, etc.

Comment: yeth, thanks, it was string)